# Cordova Splashscreen for android not showing when delay value too small

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova 5.0.0 so the Splashscreen support is integrated. I used
the code from the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html):

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi" />

    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
</platform>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
```

So for my understanding the value parameter of SplashScrenDelay should be the time how long the splashscreen is showing. however... my splashscreen is never showing on android.

Yes i added the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

And i built my project.

When i set the following value:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="50000" />
```

The Splashscreen is showing up for 50 seconds. So why isnt the 
splashscreen showing up for 5 seconds when i set it to 5000?

**EDIT 1 - Location of my splash images**

My images are stored in the root folder of the cordova project:

```
MyProject/res
```

at the same level like the config.xml.

**Edit 2 - Minimum Delay**

If it helps: I found out that the minimum delay to get the splash screen working is `40000`. But that cant be a serious minimum delay. I cant figure out why it is working with `40000` delay but not with `5000` delay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely lays on where the files are being sourced. I would look into

```
/platform/android/res
```

Theoretically on build the files should be copied from the drawable folder. Put the files in the root folder with www and platforms. Check to see if there are any errors coming up in the log when you build.

Comment: my images are in the rootfolder/res. i updated my post for that purpose. and it also wouldnt explain why the splashscreen is showing up with 50000 delay but not with 5000